Inheriting the key in key based dependency injection
I create API:s where controllers often work with multiple "sites".
(not really working with orders but used as example)
[ApiController]
[Route("{site}/Order")]
public class OrderController 
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IOrderModel> _orderModels;

    public class OrderController(Dictionary<string, IOrderModel> orderModels) 
    {
        _orderModels = orderModels;
    }

    [HttpGet("{orderNumber:int}"]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrderAsync(string site, int orderNumber)
    {
        if (!_orderModels.TryGetValue(site, out var orderModel))
            return NotFound();
        if (!User.HasAccessToSite(site))
            return Forbid();

        var order = await orderModel.GetExistingOrderAsync(orderNumber);
        
        return Ok(order)
    }
}

It works fine but I need a CreateOrderModels method where I manually work out all dependencies
private static Dictionary<string, IOrderModel> CreateOrderModels(IServiceProvider services) 
{
    var orderModels = new Dictionary<string, IOrderModel>();
    var site1Repository = services.GetRequiredService<Site1Repository>();
    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CommonOrderModel>>>();
        
    orderModels.Add("Site1", new CommonOrderModel(site1Repository, logger);
    ...
    return orderModels;
}

(It is usually just sites like "test" and "prod" so it is not a big deal but would like to use built in functionality)
I thought that with the new key based DI I could simplify the creation like
services.AddKeyedSingleton<IOrderModel, CommonOrderModel>("Site1");
services.AddKeyedSingleton<IOrderModel, SpecialSite2OrderModel>("Site2");
services.AddKeyedSingleton<IOrderModel, CommonOrderModel>("Site3");
services.AddKeyedSingleton<IRepository, Site1Repository>("Site1");
services.AddKeyedSingleton<IRepository, Site2Repository>("Site2");
services.AddKeyedSingleton<IRepository, Site3Repository>("Site3");

The problem here is that the CommonOrderModel has site specific dependencies.
What I would like to do is something like:
public CommonOrderModel([FromKeyedServices(KeyedService.ParentKey)] IRepository repository, ILogger<CommonOrderModel> logger)

i.e. When CommonOrderModel for "Site1" is created I want it to use IRepository for the same key.
I understand this is not possible out of the box. Tried to look around the source to see if I could inject the functionality somewhere but failed.
Main problem seems to be the dependency graph is not available in any factory methods so it can't get the key from higher up.
Is this at all possible?

Does IOrderModel have to be a DI service?  I see you're specifying it as a singleton, is there a compelling reason why?  There may be a solution using a DI registered factory to get an IOrderModel with the correct dependencies injected base on the site, but only if the IOrderModel instance can be a transient.  A mockup [MRE] would be helpful, to remove a lot of guesswork.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis, Singleton is is just an example. In reality dependencies have a mixture of scopes but they can probably all be transient if it helps. There is no need for IOrderModel to be a DI-service. I just need a Dictionary<string, IOrderModel> injected into the controller and I do that with a manual factory today. Just hoped key-based DI could help me avoid new OrderModel(services.GetRequiredService...)  or new OrderModel(new Repository().. which both gets tedious when the number of dependencies increases. Specially ILogger<> which is needed everywhere.

The fact there are so many interdependent repositories should be a warning sign. You should be injecting a Unit-of-Work that knows about the relations instead of trying to do this in the DI. If you use EF, the DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. It's a higher-level abstraction than single-entity CRUD classes. If you don't use EF you should create your own UoW. If you use a TransactionScope as a UoW, the design has problems

What is the actual problem? What does "multiple sites" mean? Tenants? Are you using EF or are the repositories CRUD classes? All of this matters to get to the actual solution. You do need a UoW, but you may already have one. Nothing prevents you from having multiple UoWs/DbContexts per web app. Each UoW is meant to facilitate specific business cases, not everything. In a multitenant environment though, all the cases are the same, it's "just" that the data needs to be isolated. That's easier to perform by passing the "tenant" as a parameter to the UoW instead of having multiple UoWs

@PanagiotisKanavos, the code is just an illustration of a keyed dependency having another keyed dependency. I thought using known concepts like Order and Repository would make it easier. It is an odd case also in my code but when it appears I have to fall back to a factory with GetRequiredDependency for all constructor arguments. MrCakaShaunCurtis showed how I can get around that with ActivatorUtilities so I will try that now.

@adrianm misusing repositories makes things harder. You don't need all this code, much less ActivatorUtilities if  the patterns are used correctly. A lot of the articles that show a CRUD class over a DbContext are just copy-pasta. And some are just lazy examples by authors that would never use such code in production. Adding ActivatorUtilities does nothing but hide the actual calls to RequiredService, nothing more

You can certainly achieve what you want with this overload of AddKeyedTransient(IServiceCollection, Type, Object, Func<IServiceProvider,Object,Object>)
This allows resolving dependency with delegate using passed key and service provider.
Here sample example:
// Sample services
public interface IKeyedService { }
public class KeyedService1 : IKeyedService 
{
    private readonly IKeyedDependency _dependency;

    public KeyedService1(IKeyedDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }
}
public class KeyedService2 : IKeyedService
{
    private readonly IKeyedDependency _dependency;

    public KeyedService2(IKeyedDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }
}

public interface IKeyedDependency { }
public class KeyedDependency1 : IKeyedDependency { }
public class KeyedDependency2 : IKeyedDependency { }

and the applicaiton:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

const string key1 = "key1";
const string key2 = "key2";

builder.Services.AddKeyedTransient<IKeyedDependency, KeyedDependency1>(key1);
builder.Services.AddKeyedTransient<IKeyedDependency, KeyedDependency2>(key2);

builder.Services.AddKeyedTransient<IKeyedService, KeyedService1>(key1, (sp, key) => 
    new (sp.GetRequiredKeyedService<IKeyedDependency>(key)));

builder.Services.AddKeyedTransient<IKeyedService, KeyedService2>(key2, (sp, key) =>
    new(sp.GetRequiredKeyedService<IKeyedDependency>(key)));

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/", ([FromKeyedServices(key1)] IKeyedService k1, [FromKeyedServices(key2)] IKeyedService k2) =>
{
})
.WithOpenApi();

app.Run();

And below you can see the result:


Thank you for your reply. Sorry if I was unclear but what I want is to move away from using sp.GetRequiredService for each constructor parameter and use the built in DI discovery. This more or less just moves it from a Create method into a lambda.

@adrianm I get it, but I don't know such mechanism and I doubt it exists (glad to be corrected on that). Sorry, if my insight did not help ou. Here's implementation with "inheriting" key, closest what I can think of :)

Here's what I believe is a Minimal Reproducible Example of your issue demonstrating one way to solve it.
Some dummy Repositories
public interface IRepository { }

public class Repository1 : IRepository { }
public class Repository2 : IRepository { }
public class Repository3 : IRepository { }

And Services:
public class Service1 { }
public class Service2 { }
public class Service3 { }

Two IOrderModel implementations with different constructors:
public interface IOrderModel { }

public class OrderModel1 : IOrderModel
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private string _site;
    private readonly Service1 _service1;
    private readonly Service2 _service2;
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly ILogger<OrderModel1> _logger;

    public OrderModel1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Service1 service1, Service2 service2, ILogger<OrderModel1> logger, string site)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _site = site;
        _service1 = service1;
        _service2 = service2;
        _repository = serviceProvider.GetRequiredKeyedService<IRepository>(site);
        _logger = logger;
    }
}

public class OrderModel2 : IOrderModel
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private string _site;
    private readonly Service3 _service3;
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly ILogger<OrderModel2> _logger;

    public OrderModel2(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Service3 service3, ILogger<OrderModel2> logger, string site)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _site = site;
        _service3 = service3;
        _repository = serviceProvider.GetRequiredKeyedService<IRepository>(site);
        _logger = logger;
    }
}

And the factory to get the relevant IOrderModel instance.  It uses the ActivatorUtilities utility to create the instance within the DI context, just like you would with a Transient Services, with the ability to add the missing constructor arguments. [This technique can be used to get disposable Transient Services].
public class OrderModelFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public OrderModelFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IOrderModel GetOrderModel(string site)
        => site switch
        {
            "Site1" => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<OrderModel1>(_serviceProvider, new object[] { site }),
            "Site2" => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<OrderModel2>(_serviceProvider, new object[] { site }),
            "Site3" => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<OrderModel2>(_serviceProvider, new object[] { site }),
            _ => throw new Exception("No Site defined")
        };
}

The registered services:
public static class AddServices
{
    public static void AddAppServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddKeyedScoped<IRepository, Repository1>("Site1");
        services.AddKeyedScoped<IRepository, Repository2>("Site2");
        services.AddKeyedScoped<IRepository, Repository3>("Site3");
        services.AddScoped<Service1>();
        services.AddScoped<Service2>();
        services.AddScoped<Service3>();
        services.AddScoped<OrderModelFactory>();
    }
}

And finally a test console app:
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddAppServices();
services.AddLogging();

var rootProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var serviceScope = rootProvider.CreateScope();
var provider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

var factory = provider.GetRequiredService<OrderModelFactory>();
var orderModel = factory.GetOrderModel("Site2");

Console.ReadLine();


For Reference
You can't construct and interface based service directly with ActivatorUtilities, but you can look up the defined concrete services and then create it:
public static class ServiceUtilities
{
    public static TService? GetComponentService<TService>(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider) where TService : class
    {
        var serviceType = serviceProvider.GetService<TService>()?.GetType();

        if (serviceType is null)
            return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TService>(serviceProvider);

        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(serviceProvider, serviceType) as TService;
    }
}


Looks interesting and I learned about ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance but I don't think it is necessary in your example. Just use a constructor like OrderModel(IServiceProvider sp, [ServiceKey] object site, ...) { _repo = sp.GetKeyedService<IRepo>(site); }. But your reply opened my eyes for alternative solutions. +1 for now and maybe answer later when I have tested some things.

Once you get a reference to the scoped IServiceProvider, you can do everything manually if you wish.  My example was simply to illustrate it's usage.  My intent was to open your eyes.  I use a lot more factory services now.
